# Unable to print data from android phone to Usb Printer

Tags: android, multithreading, android-usb

I am trying to connect to USB Printer and print data from it. I am using the below code to do this, following things are happening.

- I start the application from the phone - App opens and shows screen with button labelled "Print".
- When I attach the printer usb via OTG Cable, Dialog for the permission is popping up in which I select Allow permission.
- Now I press "Print" button I am seeing toasts which are placed in code

  1> "No. of devices : 1"

  2> "Device connected"

  3>  "printdata.getBytes().length ====>"
- Printer is showing "Receiving Data" but it is doing nothing afterwards. **Everything is working good but issue is Nothing gets Printed**

  ```
  public class USBAdapter {

  private UsbManager mUsbManager;
  private UsbDevice mDevice;
  UsbDevice printer = null;
  private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
  UsbDeviceConnection connection;
  String TAG = "USB";
  private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =  "com.android_usb_printer.USB_PERMISSION";


  public USBAdapter() {
  }

  public void createConn(Context context) {
      mUsbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
      HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
      if (deviceList.size() <= 0) {
          Log.i("Info", "No device found");
          Toast.makeText(context, "No device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
          Log.i("Info", "Number of device : " + deviceList.size());
          Toast.makeText(context, "Number of device : " + deviceList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
      Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

      mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
      while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
          mDevice = deviceIterator.next();
          Log.i("info", "Vendor id : " + mDevice.getVendorId());
          Log.i("info", "Product id : " + mDevice.getProductId());
          Log.i("info", "Device  name : " + mDevice.getDeviceName());
          Log.i("info", "Device class : " + mDevice.getClass().getName());
          Log.i("info", "Device protocol: " + mDevice.getDeviceProtocol());
          Log.i("info", "Device subclass : " + mDevice.getDeviceSubclass());

      }
      /*final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android_usb_printer.USB_PERMISSION";
      mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
      context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);*/
  }

  private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          System.out.println("<=======Onreceived=======>");
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
              synchronized (this) {
                  mDevice = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                  Toast.makeText(context, "mDevice ====>"+mDevice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                      if (mDevice != null) {
                          //call method to set up device communication
                      }
                  } else {
                      Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + mDevice);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  };

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public void printMessage(final Context context, String msg) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      final String printdata = msg;
      final UsbEndpoint mEndpointBulkOut;
      if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(mDevice)) {
          UsbInterface intf ;
          for(int i = 0; i < mDevice.getInterfaceCount(); i++){
              intf = mDevice.getInterface(i);
              if(intf.getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER){
                  printer = mDevice;

                  UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(i);
                  int b;
                  if (ep.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                      if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                          mEndpointBulkOut = ep;
                          connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(printer);
                          if (connection != null) {
                              Log.e("Connection:", " connected");
                              Toast.makeText(context, "Device connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }

                          Toast.makeText(context, "printdata.getBytes().length ====>"+printdata.getBytes().length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          boolean forceClaim = true;
                          connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
                          //Integer res = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointBulkOut, printdata.getBytes(), printdata.getBytes().length, 10000);
                          new Thread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  Log.i("Thread:", "in run thread");
                                  byte[] bytes = printdata.getBytes();
                                  int b = connection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointBulkOut, bytes, bytes.length, 100000);
                                  Log.i("Return Status", "b-->" + b);
                              }
                          }).start();
                          connection.releaseInterface(intf);
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      } else {
          mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
          Toast.makeText(context, "Device have no permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public void closeConnection(Context context) {
      BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              String action = intent.getAction();

              if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                  UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                  if (device != null) {
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Device closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      connection.close();
                  }
              }
          }
      };
  }
  }
  ```

`printMessage()` is being called from `onclick()` of print button in **MainActivity** point where I am going wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same issue for Cusotme made Flex printer. Though my code is working with p3 printer